# node.js sequelize hasMany relations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a question

there is a model file..

model/user.js

```
module.exports = {

  get: function () {

    //configuration database
    var database=require(""+appDir+"/config/database");

    //sequelize modul
    var Sequelize=require("sequelize");

    //set connection
    var connection = new Sequelize(database.database,database.user,database.password, {
      host: database.host,
      dialect: database.dialect,

      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
      }
    });

    //table definition
    var User = connection.define('user', {
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },

      status: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      }
    });



    //table definition
    var Tasks = connection.define('tasks', {
      taskname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },

      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      }
    });


    User.hasMany(Tasks, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
    Tasks.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});

    return User;


  }
};
```

usage following code; 
model file is called with require..
this code works without include attribute..but does not work with include attribute

```
//model call
var model=require("../model/user.js");

    model.sync().then(function()
          {
            model.find({include: [Task]}).then(function(user)
            {
              callback(user);
            })
              .catch(function(error)
              {
                callback(error);
              })
          });
```

but it does not work..I want to join two table..

Comment: try changing `user_id` to `userId`

Answer (score 0):

You export only get function in model/user.js, but then you're trying to call sync function, that is not defined. First, try to get user model (Sequelize model), then call sync function of it:

```
var model = require("../model/user.js");
model.get().sync()
```